# Praw: API Login Fails with Client Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-403, reddit, praw

I couldn't log into my own Reddit account using the code below.

Error message:

```
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden
```

Is there a way to get around this error?

```
class PrawTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.out.write('Yo, imma redit bot!')

    get_login= ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    get_login.read("logins.ini")

    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Captain Reddit!')

    r.login(get_login.get("login1", "username"),get_login.get("login1","password"))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/hype_shit_up', PrawTest)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very needlessly over-complicated just to login with PRAW. The way reccomended in [the documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is to have `reddit = praw.Reddit('SOME-NAME-HERE')` to login. Then, in your `praw.ini` file, set it up to look like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
# A boolean to indicate whether or not to check for package updates.
check_for_updates=True

# Object to kind mappings
comment_kind=t1
message_kind=t4
redditor_kind=t2
submission_kind=t3
subreddit_kind=t5

# The URL prefix for OAuth-related requests.
oauth_url=https://oauth.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for regular requests.
reddit_url=https://www.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for short URLs.
short_url=https://redd.it

[SOME-NAME-HERE]
user_agent=USER-AGENT-HERE
username=REDDIT-ACCOUNT-USERNAME
password=REDDIT-ACCOUNT-PASSWORD
client_id=REDDIT-APP-CLIENT-ID
client_secret=REDDIT-APP-CLIENT-SECRET
```

Requirements for the user agent are found [here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API):

Change your client's User-Agent string to something unique and descriptive, including the target platform, a unique application identifier, a version string, and your username as contact information, in the following format:
`<platform>:<app ID>:<version string> (by /u/<reddit username>)`

-`Example: User-Agent: android:com.example.myredditapp:v1.2.3 (by /u/kemitche)`

- Many default User-Agents (like "Python/urllib" or "Java") are drastically limited to encourage unique and descriptive user-agent strings.
- Including the version number and updating it as you build your application allows us to safely block old buggy/broken versions of your app.
- **NEVER lie about your user-agent.** This includes spoofing popular browsers and spoofing other bots. We will ban liars with extreme prejudice.

If you have any future questions dont hesitate to ask them as a comment to this answer!